# How to make code flexible enough so blank column value is filtered same as nan?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create logic that is fired off only when a particular row integer in the index is present and in the same row if a particular column is empty.

The dataframe has a code where all 'nan' are filled with blanks like so:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

This is the logic I am using to see if a particular row integer exists and if the column is null:

```
   if 12 in df.index:
        if df.col1.isnull()[12] == True:
            [rest of the code]
```

The `isnull` is not picking up that blank for the row is null.

How do I make my code flexible enough to say that blank is null ? or do I have to replace blanks with NaN?

Ideally I want to avoid the latter option because to add back the `nan` I have to use `np.nan` and for the serverless architecture I want to avoid adding more libraries since the original package only contains pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to `replace` blank with null

```
df=df.replace({'' : np.nan})
```

Or we can adding one more condition

```
if 12 in df.index:
        if df.col1.isnull()[12] or (df.col1[12]==''):
            [rest of the code]
```